# prevent validation while the datepicker has focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the jQuery-ui [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) together with Jörn Zaefferer's [validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugin.

It's well known that validate does not automatically fire *after* a datepicker changes the content of an input field.

What I find curious is that validate *does* fire when the year dropdown is clicked, when the month dropdown is clicked and when the day is clicked. And, in none of these cases has the value of the input field been changed.  You can try for yourself here: http://jsfiddle.net/ECku3/12/ There are console.log events that show when the validation method is called and the value of the validated field when `$.validator.showErrors()` is called.

### tl;dr

I would like to find a way to prevent validation while the datepicker has focus. But I do not want to prevent validation when a user types a date instead of using the datepicker. So I can't just set `$.validator.settings.onfocusout = false`.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the [jquery.ui.datepicker.validation.js](http://keith-wood.name/uiDatepickerValidation.html) plug-in like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        firstDay: 1,
        showOn: 'button',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,

    });

    $("#mydate").datepicker();
    $('#myform').validate({ 
        errorPlacement: $.datepicker.errorPlacement, 
        rules: { 
            mydate: { 
                required: true, 
                dpDate: function(){traceBack(); return true;},
                dpCompareDate: 'notBefore 2011-01-01' 
            } 
        }, 
        messages: { 
            mydate: 'Please enter a valid date (yyyy-mm-dd) after 2011-01-01'
        }});

    function traceBack() {
        console.log("Firing?");
    }
});​
```

**Edit**

If you really don't want any validate events to be fired while navigating in the datepicker widget, you can switch off the onfocusout setting when the datepicker widget is visible:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        firstDay: 1,
        showOn: 'button',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        beforeShow: function () {$("#myform").validate().settings.onfocusout = false; },
        onClose: function () {$("#myform").validate().settings.onfocusout = true;}
    });

    $("#mydate").datepicker();
    $('#myform').validate({ 
        errorPlacement: $.datepicker.errorPlacement, 
        rules: { 
            mydate: { 
                required: true, 
                dpDate: function(){traceBack(); return true;},
                dpCompareDate: 'notBefore 2011-01-01' 
            } 
        }, 
        messages: { 
            mydate: 'Please enter a valid date (yyyy-mm-dd) after 2011-01-01'
        }});

    function traceBack() {
        console.log("Firing?");
    }

});​
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/Bn7gy/24/

Comment: `datepicker.validation` is a nice plugin. But it doesn't address the issue I'm talking about.  I've added a console.log() to your fiddle to show when validation fires (http://jsfiddle.net/Bn7gy/4/ ). It fires appropriately when the field loses focus.  It fires once each for no good reason (since the date has not actually changed yet) as you pick a year, a month, and a day from the datepicker. Then it fires appropriately when the date has been completely selected.

Comment: Unfortunately, turning off `onfocusout` means that the validation no longer happens when the user types in the date.  As I noted in my OP, that's not an option for me.

Comment: What does `validateDelegate` do? So far as I can see, turning off events should mean it doesn't need to be overridden. But my javascript is weaker than I'd like, so a good explanation of the original function would be very welcome.

Comment: Please ignore the `validateDelegate` part - it was the wrong version in the fiddle and it doesn't do anything. Edited answer above - this was the only way I could get validation of keypresses and avoid validate events firing when navigating the datepicker.

Comment: Perfect!  I kept trying to make the validator do it. But it makes much more sense to have the datepicker control it.